# How to get maximum number of transaction by a pair in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table given below:

```
    Tid.    Source.           Destination
    10.        A.                    B
    11.        A.                    C
    12.        A.                    D
    13.        B.                    C
    14.        C.                    B
    15.        D.                    A
    16.        C.                    A
    17.        C.                    A
```

Now the scenario is we have to count the transaction with considering A to C and C to A  or( C to B and B to C) as a same combination.
It means count of transactions will be 3 .

Comment: What makes these "in a same group"?  Simply count where Source=A and Dest=C OR Source=C and Dest=A.

Comment: @Tab like there is two case one is from US to Uk and another is from Uk to US but I want to get the count of transactions on the pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a case statement to construct the pairs on which to group:

```
select
  case when source <= destination then source else destination end mincol,
  case when source >= destination then source else destination end maxcol,
  count(*) counter
from tablename
group by 
  case when source <= destination then source else destination end, 
  case when source >= destination then source else destination end
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7df715b16e6ec7e665f13162bbc102cf).
Results:

```
mincol | maxcol | counter
:----- | :----- | ------:
A      | B      |       1
A      | C      |       3
B      | C      |       2
A      | D      |       2
```

Comment: just suppose we have usa and delhi if i will compare usa with delhi how it will compare in case statement I mean how will it find which is greater than or less than.

Comment: The comparison is alphabetical but this is not important. The comparison is only done just to return distinct pairs.

Comment: Thanks for explanation @forpas just can we replace <= with= and >= with =.

Comment: *replace <= with= and >= with =* why? This does not make sense.

Comment: You can replace <= with < and >= with > if source and destination can never be equal.

Comment: @fopas thanks yes I got it actually it is comparing then creating new pair.

Comment: It is creating the same pair for A,B and B,A.

Comment: thanks  now I need to get the row of maximum counter.

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a878cedd02a201631bcbc7363c7204ab

Comment: Can I have another option to contact you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't do any other contacts out of SO.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, particularly regarding "same group".

```
select count(*)
from YourTable
where (Source = 'A.' and Destination = 'C')
      or (Source = 'C.' and Destination = 'A')
```

Extrapolated generically:

```
declare @YourTable table (Tid int, Source varchar(1), Destination varchar(1))

insert into @YourTable
values (10,'A','B')
      ,(11,'A','C')
      ,(12,'A','D')
      ,(13,'B','C')
      ,(14,'C','B')
      ,(15,'D','A')
      ,(16,'C','A')
      ,(17,'C','A')

select 'Combination ' + case when Source < Destination then Source + ', ' + Destination else Destination + ', ' + Source end Combination, count(*) Count
from @YourTable
group by case when Source < Destination then Source + ', ' + Destination else Destination + ', ' + Source end
```

Output

```
Combination         Count
Combination A, B    1
Combination A, C    3
Combination A, D    2
Combination B, C    2
```

Comment: can we make it dynamic there are multiple values in a pair?